# How would I convert a double value to hh:mm?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, time, double, percentage

As it says above...
I don't need the seconds with that as it does not constantly update.
I have searched around this site and google for a few hours and couldn't find anything exactly like what I need.
Here is my code:

```
//Sets the percentage calculation
double percent = level / 100;
//Calculates the time left while using the following
double a = 40 * percent;
double b = 400 * percent;
double c = 7 * percent;
double d = 6 * percent;

aTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", a];
bTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", b];
cTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", c];
dTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", d];
```

After a calculation of, say, 50% of 7 hours, it currently gives 3.5 hours.  I want it to say 3:30.

The calculations, as you can see, are static minus the level calculation, I just need to know how to convert the decimal to hh:mm (maybe even days for the 400 hours one).

Note: all the numbers above (40, 400, 7, 6) are in hours.

Comment: [Modulus arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) -- `%` in C-like languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
double hours = 7; 
double percent = 0.5; // 50 percent
int value = hours * percent * 60; // value in minutes
NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",value/60,value%60];
NSLog(@"%@",formatted);
```

Output:

```
03:30
```